# How to use $.when when the number of getJSON URLs is variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm chaining `getJSON` requests with `.when`.

Code is similar to this:

```
 $.when( $.getJSON(url0),$.getJSON(url1), $.getJSON(url2)).done( function() {
    $.each(arguments, function(index, result) { …
```

How can I write this so if the URL set contains url3 or url4 or more or only url0 it can proceed?

I store the url vars in a file or in local storage.

Comment: You can make an array and u can process that array values inside $.when

Comment: okay wait let me answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var list = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5'];
  var callback = function() {
    console.log("done");
  };
  var requests = [];

    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      requests.push($.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        success: function() {
          console.log('suc');
        }
      }));
    }

  $.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(results){callback()});
```

You can give me some more details so i can load that in array and can show you how that works

**JSFIDDLE DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/MBZEu/4/**

or you can try

```
  var urlArr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5'];
  var callback = function() {
    console.log("done");
  };
  var requests = [];

    for(i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
      requests.push($.getJSON(urlArr[i])); //or something similar which can push url in array
    }

  $.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(results){callback()});
```

or use this to see whats going on with req

```
requests.push($.getJSON(urlArr[i], function(res){console.log(res)}));
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I'm storing a value in local storage which is used to build the actual URL. Works like this: [JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('item:1')).url].

Comment: Gee, why in the world would someone downvote this before it's even tried?

Comment: now it is correct if you try then feedback me or i will cange code accourding to your need

Comment: Thanks!~ I need to head for a lunch but will try when I return. I need to see how you are building the string inside of the .when ($.getJSON(url0),$.getJSON(url1), $.getJSON(url2))

Comment: Thanks,again. I have been able to use this as a basis to accomplish my goal. However, it raises some design issues. For example, I don't know how to determine the number of items in a user's local storage so I will fall trying to get a length.